# c# compare strings with a comparison function

Tags: c#

I may be missing the obvious but how do I provide a compare function to string.Equals() ?

I need to test for string equality but allow the first letter to be of a different case, so `StringComparison` is not useful, but I can't see a way to provide my own function to string.Equals ?

```
var s1="John";
var s2="john";

if (string.Equals(s1, s2, ????)) console.Write("Equal!!");
```

Comment: You should do this in high level classes. For example if you want to sort `List<string>` or `IEnumerable<string>` you can provide your own function.

Comment: Can you add some code? It sounds like you should implement `IEqualityComparer<string>`.

Comment: Thx @Lee - what function receives  IEqualityComparer<string> ?

Comment: @Kofifus you want to allow only the first lettter to be case insensitive, or do you want to just do a case insensitive string comparison

Comment: only the first letter

Comment: @kofifus -  The one you need to test for equality in. If you don't need to do this generically you can just create a separate function which implements the test you need. It's impossible to say without seeing the code you're trying to write.

Comment: added some code

Comment: Can you share the examples if the strings you want to compare and the expected output of comparison?

Comment: Write yourself an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Answer (score 2):

The `Equals` method does not have an overload that takes a custom compare function, but you could write one as an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool EqualsCaseExceptFirst(this string input, string other)
    {
        if (input == null) throw new NullReferenceException();
        if (ReferenceEquals(input, other)) return true;
        if (input.Length != other.Length) return false;
        if (input.Length == 0) return true;
        if (!input.Substring(0, 1).Equals(other.Substring(0, 1), 
            StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;

        return input.Length == 1 || input.Substring(1).Equals(other.Substring(1));
    }
}
```

A sample test might look like:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var testStrings = new List<string>
    {
        "hello", "Hello", "HELLO", "hELLO"
    };

    var sample = "Hello";

    foreach (var testString in testStrings)
    {
        var result = sample.EqualsCaseExceptFirst(testString);
        Console.WriteLine($"'{sample}' == '{testString}'  :  {result}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("----------");

    sample = "HELLO";

    foreach (var testString in testStrings)
    {
        var result = sample.EqualsCaseExceptFirst(testString);
        Console.WriteLine($"'{sample}' == '{testString}'  :  {result}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

You mentioned in the comments that you want to create an `IEqualityComparer` class, so here's a sample that simply reuses this method:

```
class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string first, string second)
    {
        return first?.EqualsCaseExceptFirst(second) ?? false;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        return obj?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thx, I was just wondering if there's a way to use IEqualityComparer<string> or provide a lambda .. thx

Comment: @kofifus, yes of course there is a way to use `IEqualityComparer<string>`. Write a class that implements this interface and use the code example(s) in the answers here to implement the Equals method from the interface. Et voilà. Similarly, you can use the code from the answers inside the body of a lambda expression...

Comment: yeah but where do I pass this class to ? string.Equals does not accept IEqualityComparer<string>

Comment: It's an extension method (which means it will automatically appear to belong to the `string` class natively). Did you see the provided example? If that doesn't work, please specify the context with which you're using it. I added a sample class at the bottom of how this could be used in another class that implements `IEqualityComparer<string>`

Comment: @kofifus, you can provide an `IEqualityComparer<T>` in some way to anything that can make use of `IEqualityComparer<T>`; for example dictionaries, HashSets, etc...

Comment: yeah but that is not my case, I need to provide it to a `Linq` `where`

Comment: @kofifus `.Where(item => item.EqualsCaseExceptFirst("something"))`. Or using your sample code, `if (s1.EqualsCaseExceptFirst(s2))`. If those don't work **please update your question with more details**.

Comment: @kofifus, then don't bother about `IEqualityComparer<string>`. Just use the equality comparison functions as provided here in the answers to build your Linq clauses...

Answer (score 1):

You could just roll your own, add pepper and salt to taste

```
  public static bool MyStringEquals(this string str1, string str2, StringComparison comparison = StringComparison.CurrentCulture)
      => !(str1?.Length > 0) || !(str2?.Length > 0) || string.Equals(str1.Substring(1), str2.Substring(1),comparison);
```

**Usage**

```
var s1 = "asd";
var s2 = "bsd";

var result = s1.MyStringEquals(s2, StringComparison.Ordinal);
```

Obviously, you will want to write yourself a bunch of test cases, and work out if this is what you want

Comment: ok yeah of course, I was just wondering if there's a way to use IEqualityComparer<string> or provide a lambda .. thx

Comment: @kofifus yeah i didn't know how far you wanted to go down this rabbit hole, though it would be a good candidate for a unit test,and possibly break apart the expression body in to more direct branching and so its easier to understand the logic. Good luck